# when I run my code i get this error

Tags: widget, wxpython, python-3.5

self.Frame = Frame(image) TypeError: Frame(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:   overload 1: too many arguments   overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'Image'

```
import wx
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,image,parent  = None, id=-1,pos=wx.DefaultPosition, title='Hello, wxPytho!'):
        temp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
        size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHeight()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        image = wx.Image('wxPython.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        self.Frame = Frame(image)
        self.Frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.Frame)
        return True


def main():
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indenting?

Comment: nothing will change if i fix the indentation it is just a mistake that happened when i copied the code

Comment: Making Code more readable (indentation) helps to get better answers. -1 for not following advise given.

Comment: i said that because i didn't find where to edit my code, and I really appreciate your advice

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method has 2 underscores before and after not 1 (`_init_`) which is how you have defined it twice But you got it correct for `__main__`.
Also `self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)` should be `self.SetTopWindow(self.Frame)`

When starting out, try to use names that don't mimic keywords, or at least stick something in the name like `myFrame` so that it is clear that it is your name and not a keyword.

For your information, indentation is vitally important within python and most other programming languages that I have used, come to that.

The code should read:

```
import wx
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,image,parent  = None, id=-1,pos=wx.DefaultPosition,title='Hello, wxPytho!'):
        temp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
        size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHeight()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        image = wx.Image('wxPython.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        self.Frame = Frame(image)
        self.Frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.Frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
           main()
```

A less complicated way of achieving something similar would be like this

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        Img = wx.Image("wxPython.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        Imgsize = Img.GetWidth()+15, Img.GetHeight()+35
        self.SetSize(Imgsize)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.BitmapFromImage(Img))
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Image Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i got another error: "C:\Users\new\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Wxpython.py", line 13, in OnInit
    self.Frame = Frame(image)
  File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Wxpython.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp)
TypeError: StaticBitmap(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: 'parent' is not a valid keyword argument
  overload 2: 'bitmap' is not a valid keyword argument

Comment: I am unable to replicate your error. Did you copy and paste the above code? If not, try replacing your code with the code above. `StaticBitmap(parent, id=ID_ANY, bitmap=NullBitmap, pos=DefaultPosition,
             size=DefaultSize, style=0, name=StaticBitmapNameStr)`

Comment: I have tested the code on Linux with python 2.7.12 wx3.0-gtk2 and python 3.5.2 wx4.0.02b gtk2 I suggest you try the second option I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the upper revised version by @Rolf of Saxony. Worked on Python 3.6 (Winpython distro).

Tried the same with Python 3.5, which still had wxPython-Phoenix 3.0.3 something. Showed the same exception with the match overload. Solution:

```
pip uninstall wxPython-Phoenix

pip install wxPython
```

Works now fine also on Python 3.5.

Taking back the downvote.